# Need some help in understanding a step-function notation

Tags: step-function

So I was reading this paper and I saw this nonsmooth nonlinear function. But, I am not familiar with this kind of notation, does it denote some kind of a step-function with the value $1$ if $X \leq a$ True and $0$ otherwise?

$$g_0,_j(X_{ji})=4[1(X_{ji}\leq0.25)+1(X_{ji}\leq0.5)+1(X_{ji}\leq0.75)-1.5]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is an Indicator function: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), which is defined as follows

$$1_A(x) :=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } x\in A,\\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

As an alternative notation, one may also give:

$$1(x\in A) :=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } x\in A,\\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

In your case, the second notation is used. Therefore $1(X_{ji}\leq 0.25) =\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } X_{ji}\leq0.25,\\
0, & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$